# how to disable data-table sorting functionalities from fnDrawCallback event

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, datatable, datatables

I want to disable sorting functionalities of a data-table. So i am using below code and its working fine.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
  { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
] } );
```

But i want to disable data-table sorting functionalities from **fnDrawCallback** event.
Please help.